# Do all keyholders in a multisig wallet have separate wallet addresses that all work as the "multisig wallet"?

Tags: multi-signature

I have a 3/5 multisig bitcoin wallet. I understand all 5 signers have their own set of private keys and public keys. What I don't understand is how the "receiving" addresses work. Does each set of keys have its own set of addresses and it doesn't matter which addresses funds are deposited to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is a single multisig address, which can be computed from *all* the participants' keys.

Funds can then be sent to that multisig address, and when 3 out of the 5 predetermined keys associated with the address sign, that money can be spent.

Comment: Thanks - question: when you say "single multisig adress", you mean several addresses from the extended public key? I've been sending to a new address on the multisig wallet every single transaction.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. In that case a new address is generated, each using a new key from every participant, which are generated in lock-step from those participants' xpubs. The point I was trying to make is that that each individual multisig address has contributions from each participant. It's not an address per participant.